# Express cross section in terms of tranverse momentum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering-cross-section, analyticity

im new here.
I have an expression for a differential cross section of a process two in two at fixed center of mass energy $\sqrt{s}$, $\frac{d\sigma}{dt}$, in terms of the three Mandelstam variables $s$, $t$, $u$.

I need to express it in terms of the transverse momentum of the first outcoming particle and of the second. How can I do it?

I thought to write $u$ in terms of $t$ using the relation:
$$s+t+u=\sum m_j^2$$
and after this I don't know how to write $t$ in term of $p_T$ of the first incoming particle.
Thanks
Antonio